# use custom control directly in Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, listview, custom-controls

i want to use the listview flicker"less" control found here [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210118172015/http://geekswithblogs.net/CPound/archive/2006/02/27/70834.aspx)

directly in my c# Project.
i dont want to make a custom user control project, build it to dll and then import it in my project. i just want this all in my c# Programm i am making.

i think i have to add in my project a class, and add the code, but how can i use the control now directly in my project?

Comment: What do you mean by "using it directly"? Is it not appearing in a designer somewhere or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio, right-click on your project and then click `ADD | USER CONTROL`.  Name the new control `ListViewNF` and click `ADD`.

View the code for the new class.  Change this line:

```
public partial class ListViewNF : UserControl
```

to this:

```
public partial class ListViewNF : ListView
```

and Rebuild.  You'll get a compiler error about `AutoScaleMode` - just delete the line in `InitializeComponent` that's causing the error:

```
// delete this line:
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
```

So far, your code will look like this:

```
public partial class ListViewNF : ListView 
{ 
    public ListViewNF() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Change it to this:

```
public partial class ListViewNF : ListView
{
    public ListViewNF()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Activate double buffering
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | 
            ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

        //Enable the OnNotifyMessage event so we get a chance to filter out 
        // Windows messages before they get to the form's WndProc
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.EnableNotifyMessage, true);
    }

    protected override void OnNotifyMessage(Message m)
    {
        //Filter out the WM_ERASEBKGND message
        if (m.Msg != 0x14)
        {
            base.OnNotifyMessage(m);
        }
    }

}
```

Rebuild your project, and you should now see the `ListViewNF` in your Toolbox of controls on the left (right at the top).  You can drag this control onto a form in the designer, just like a regular `ListView`.

Comment: Hi ...
thanks ..
that is exactly what i was looking for ..
(i didnt knew that the control will be listed on the top of the list, it was there but i didnt see it !!!!!!!)
thanks anyway to you all ..
i also tried the option with adding it directly into code, and creating instance, and it works toooo

thanks all

Comment: In Visual Studio 2010. First: For a 32 assembly. It was not there automatically. I had to do "Choose Items...", as described below. Second: It did not work with 64 bit assemblies (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/963017)

Answer (score 0):

Open a toolbox in your visual studio project. Then click 'choose items'. Click browse, and select an assembly, which contains a control. Now you can use a control within a designer. Hope that is what you are asking about.

Comment: please attend this :
i dont want to make a custom user control project, build it to dll and then import it in my project ..i just want this all in my c# Programm iam making..

Comment: If this control is not distributed as a separate assembly, than you have to somehow build it.You don't have to make a separate project for that, just use the code in your existing project, i don't really see the problem...